# How to optimize deep nested foreignKeys in Django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

**TLDR;**

Is there a better way to handle deep nesting in this Django queryset?

```
File.objects.filter(folder__project__workspace__organization__in=user.organizations.all())
```

---

**Detailed question:**

Here is an example scenario:

An organization consists of multiple users and a user can be part of multiple organizations.

```
class User(models.Model):
    pass


class Organization(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, through='OrganizationMembership', related_name='organizations'
    )

class OrganizationMembership(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(User)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
```

The nested relationship among models are defined as follows:

```
class Workspace(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, related_name='workspaces')


class Project(models.Model):
    workspace = models.ForeignKey(Workspace, related_name='projects')


class Folder(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='folders')


class File(models.Model):
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder, related_name='files')
```

I wanted to filter all the files the requesting user has access to across organizations. Here is my queryset, **is there a way to optimize this queryset?**

```
user = self.request.user
organizations = user.organizations.all()

File.objects.filter(folder__project__workspace__organization__in=organizations)
```

Answer (score 2):

Approach : `rather than running one complex and large query(having multiple joins), run small simple queries on DB`

The given solution may be more optimal than the one obtained by joining of multiple tables which is in the above given code above.

I am assuming that Each of the table has a primary key named `id`. And just because there is an implicit index on the primary key column, the below code should be more fast. Downside is that it consume more memory if the number of records in the tables are very large.

```
user = self.request.user
organizations = user.organizations.all()
organizations_ids = organizations.values_list('id', flat=True)
reduced_organization_qs = Organization.objects.filter(ids__in=organizations_ids)
reduced_organization_ids = reduced_organization_qs.values_list('id', flat=True)

reduced_workspace_qs = Workspace.objects.filter(organizations_ids=reduced_organization_ids)
reduced_workspace_ids = reduced_workspace_qs.values_list('id', flat=True)


reduced_project_qs = Project.objects.filter(workspace_id__in=reduced_workspace_ids)
reduced_project_ids = reduced_project_qs.values_list('id', flat=True)

reduced_folder_qs = Folder.objects.filter(project_id__in=reduced_project_ids)
reduced_folder_ids = reduced_folder_qs.values_list('id', flat=True)

reduced_file_qs = File.objects.filter(folder_id__in=reduced_folder_ids)
```

What i am doing is i am skipping the joining of tables and just because there is index on `id` , retreival of ids will be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Use "query" to get the generated SQL :

```
MyModel.objects.filter(name="my name").query
```

I think there is no better way than your current method.